# Date Parsing Exception Java

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I am not able to parse date while converting 12hr datetime format to 24hr datetime format.the code is

```
    List_CallDateTime=rs.getString(5);
    System.out.print(List_CallDateTime);
    String str=List_CallDateTime;
    SimpleDateFormat callreadFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm aa",Locale.US);
    SimpleDateFormat callwirteformat=new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy HH:mm",Locale.US);
    Date calldate=null;
    calldate=callreadFormat.parse(str);
    String callcreatedate=callwirteformat.format(calldate);
    System.out.println("asdsad"+callcreatedate);
```

and the exception that I get is

```
StandardWrapperValve[jsp]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "04/25/2012  9:00AM"
```

Comment: The seconds are missing in the date you offer but the conversion format specifies seconds.

Comment: Cleared but still i get the same exception again

Comment: What is the datatype of table `field`?

Comment: You should have to call `getTimestamp` method. e.g `callwirteformat.format(rs.getTimestamp(5))`

Answer (score 1):

You can easily format the `smalldatetime` field using,

```
 SimpleDateFormat writeFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy HH:mm"
                                                          ,Locale.US);
 String strDate=writeFormat.format(rs.getTimestamp(5));
```